# Trivialization of rank-$r$ vector bundle gives a non vanishing local section

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Its known that local trivialization of a line bundle $L$ on a smooth projective curve are equivalent to non vanishing local sections ([reference](https://books.google.fr/books?id=RSr0Ylq3DyoC&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=trivialization%20gives%20a%20non%20vanishing%20local%20section&source=bl&ots=GStQVx78PJ&sig=ACfU3U3RyqKba3BP5JT3uSHOH5NF1Vb6mg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSueT8sJXpAhVt8-AKHYxaCVkQ6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=trivialization%20gives%20a%20non%20vanishing%20local%20section&f=false)).

> Is it still true for rank-$r$ vector bundle $ E$?

My guess is that it is also true, since $ E$ is just the direct sum of line bundles, so we can construct a non vanishing local section on $ E$ from the components of the non vanishing local section of $ L$. Does it make sence?

Comment: Vector bundles are not in general direct sum of line bundles.

Comment: Thank you @Mohan. I thought it was the case for locally free rank-$r$ vector bundle as $ E\cong \bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^n \mathcal  O_X$. So if $L\cong \mathcal O_X$, don't we have $ E\cong \bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^n L$? (maybe the magic word is locally free?)

Comment: Vector bundles are always locally free, that's what a vector bundle is, but that doesn't mean it's a direct sum of line bundles.

Comment: Thank you MattSamuel and Mohan, indeed I remember now the equivalence of categories between vector bundles and lcoally free sheaves